# Hibernate generates negative id after a certain amount of insert

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a weird behavior of Hibernate (3.6.1.Final) in my application and I am pretty desperate at the moment. The behavior occurs on both MariaDB 10.1 and RDS on Amazon.

After a certain amount of successful persists (always around ~5k) Hibernate fires a:

```
SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

From what I see in the stacktrace Hibernate tries to fill a foreign key in a entity with a **negative value** that violates the FK constraint (the target table of the FK does not have such primary key value).

The strange thing is:

- It happens only after around ~5k successful persists
- After submitting such number of persist operation, the error occurs even if I restart the application (as well as the DB). Only solution is to wipe out the DB and repeat.
- The error occurs independently from the load (continuous, in batches, single or multithread).

The following is the FK of the entity that is violated during the insert:

```
    @Entity
    @Cacheable
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    public class Charge extends Entry {

        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "totalId")
        private Amount total;
     //....
```

And this is how the primary key is defined in the Amount entity:

```
     @GeneratedValue
     @Id
     @Column(nullable = false)
     private Integer pk;
     //....
```

My questions are:

- Why a non-valid negative value occurs in the FK ? (the primary key targeted by the FK is set as auto increment, starting from one and all the preceeding inserts worked perfectly accordingly to this)
- Why does the error occurs only after ~5k persists  ?
- Why not even a restart of the application fix the problem? DB is fine because a manual insert outside the application works (with valid FK values)

My suspicion is Hibernate and how it manages the auto_increment on the DB. The are many posts on the topic but none of them fit my specific case (error occurring only after a certain usage).

Last note: On the DB auto_increment is initially set to 1. All the initial persists (before the error appears) of the Amount entity have a incremental PK that start by 1: (1,2,3, ...). So again why after a while Hibernate comes up with a negative (incompatible to the FK)?

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Best
G.

Comment: How is the primary key defined on the DB side ?

Comment: What negative value? `-1`? Or some random negative value? Does the absolute value match any existing foreign keys?

Comment: The primary key on the DB for the Amount table is defined as follows: `pk` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

Comment: The negative value is something around ah high negative number, something like -32656 or similar

Answer (score 2):

#### Maybe is the limite of type int ?

Try this :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column (name = "id")
private long id;
```

Comment: As far as I can see in source code default strategy is already auto,  well 5k still in Integer range and Autoboxing just might throw npe instead of having weird negative values
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-api/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.java

Comment: But I agree it is worth too try long

Comment: Sry i can' t help, it's weird : (

Answer (score 0):

we had exact the same issue and it was due to old mariadb jdbc driver. We were using version 1.4.2
After switching to the version 1.5.5 of mariadb jdbc driver the problem were gone

Comment: and here is the related bug report on MariaDB Connector-J project https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-284